# Qt6 QWidgetAction replacement for 'setMenu'?

Tags: qt, pyqt

in `Qt5` I used a `QWidgetAction` to create a custom looking menu entry, then I added a submenu to it using the `setMenu` method.
But in `Qt6` the `setMenu` method has been removed, how can this be achieved in `Qt6`? How can a menu item be created with custom widgets in it **and** a submenu?

Thanks

Comment: What do you need `setMenu` for?

Comment: To create a submenu item with custom widgets in it. `QMenu::addMenu` only allows for the standard `icon / text / shorcut` item, but I need a custumizable item with a submenu.

Comment: Ok, I see. Btw I see that `setMenu()` is "just" deprecated (maybe they will replace it at some point), but it should still be available (see in the [obsolete members list](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qaction-obsolete.html#setMenu)).

Comment: Unfortumately, `menu()` and `setMenu()` just don't exist at all in PyQt6 because they are implemented as template methods in C++. It's still possible to add a menu with `QMenu.addMenu`, but that returns the menu's `menuAction`, which is obviously useless if you want to use a sub-class of `QAction`. It looks like this functionality will remain missing unless the maintainer of PyQt6 can be persuaded to add some special-cased methods to work around the issue. (Note that the same problem has been resolved in PySide6 - see [PYSIDE-1627](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/PYSIDE-1627)).

Comment: It should be noted that since this question was posted, the problem was fixed for PyQt too, at least starting with version 6.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was made obsolete in [this](https://codereview.qt-project.org/c/qt/qtbase/+/294395) upstream Qt Change.

It personally concerns me that this was made obsolete leaving the API documentation reader clueless at first.

Digging a bit deeper, it seems that the reason for obsoleting this method is that `QAction` was moved from `QtWidgets` to `QtGui`. This is to have generic actions both in the `QtWidgets` and `QtQuick` worlds. It would be suboptimal to duplicate this in both worlds. So far so good. It makes sense.

It is also worth mentioning that the API is not yet removed. It is just deprecated. I think it would ever be removed if no one, like yourself, brings this up, or there is a proper replacement for it. So, be assured that it would not just be gone anytime soon.

Now, for the future, a `QWidgetAction` is represented in the containers you add it to by whatever widget you return from createWidget.

It seems that you could still use these APIs:

[`void QWidget::addAction(QAction *action)`](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt6-dev/qwidget.html#addAction)

and

[`QAction *QMenu::menuAction() const`](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt6-dev/qmenu.html#menuAction)

With [`QWidgetAction`](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt6-dev/qwidgetaction.html).

If this still does not cover your use case, I would suggest to open a [Jira ticket](https://bugreports.qt.io) against the Qt bug tracker to propose a `QMenu::setMenuInAction` method to replace the obsolete.

Answer (score -1):

If you are inside of a `QToolbar`, you can use `QToolButton`'s `setMenu()`:

```cpp
    QMenu *menu = new QMenu();
    // build your menu
    // ...

    // Create the button, and add it to the toolbar
    QToolButton *toolButton = new QToolButton(menu);
    toolButton->setPopupMode(QToolButton::InstantPopup);
    toolButton->setMenu(menu);
    addWidget(toolButton);    // or toolbar->addWidget()
```

Comment: The OP clearly explained that they are talking about a "custom menu entry", which is part of a QMenu.

Comment: I see. I have fairly basic Qt skills and it wasn't clear to me that a "custom menu entry" was exclusive to QMenu. Although it may not solve OP's problem (and OP has already marked it solved), I think this answer adds to the reader's options, particularly since this is the first google hit and the only article with potential solutions on the removal of setMenu in Qt6.

Comment: The question was initially tagged for PyQt, because the migration of QAction into QtGui made the `menu()` and `setMenu()` functions not available anymore. The issue was initially present in PySide too, but both bindings were eventually fixed. In reality, the functions were *never* removed in the standard Qt (I don't know why they removed the tag), and were only temporarily marked as obsolete until 6.1, then reinstated since 6.3. So, since you're using C++, you should never have had any problem at all.

Comment: Gotcha, I see now the reason I'm having trouble in C++ is because setMenu is marked deprecated in 6.2 (the version included in Ubuntu 22.04) and I have enabled QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000. When I turn that off I'm able to compile again, but since I'm maintaining a project that must support both Qt5 and Qt6 (including 6.2 and 6.5) for the time being, I will need to stick the with above workaround. Thanks for shedding light on the problem!

Comment: Maybe you should consider using that declaration with a more specific version, or possibly avoid it at all and eventually decide behavior case by case. Unfortunately, the 6.2 docs are not available in the archive, so I don't know if they actually restored it in 6.2 or 6.3. Note that since you're using a custom QWidgetAction, you may consider overriding `createWidget()` and directly return a QToolButton with the menu already set.